# Replace a text in a variable using sed or awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a variable with the value as below,

```
var1="heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:testapp-sandbox,external-dns/resource=ingress/monitoring/prometheus-operator-grafana"

var2=us-east-1:testapp-dev
```

I want to replace only the text between ***owner=*** and ***,external-dns***  which is ***us-east-1:testapp-sandbox***  with the content from var2.

So I am expecting output as below,

```
var1_updated="heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:testapp-dev,external-dns/resource=ingress/monitoring/prometheus-operator-grafana"
```

I tried this ,  `sed -i 's/(owner=).*(,external-dns)/\1us-east-1:testapp-dev\2/g' value.txt`   but its throwing me error as invalid command code v

Please let me know how to do this using sed or awk...

Comment: What have you searched/tried/experimented ?

Comment: I tried this ,  sed -i 's/(owner=).*(,external-dns)/\1us-east-1:testapp-dev2/g' value.txt   but its throwing me error as invalid command code v

Comment: **Always add your (even failed) attempts to your original post**

Comment: I have added my attempt now

Comment: `invalid command code v` means nothing, seems truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is close to valid, just use *extented regex* with `-E` switch :

```
sed -E 's/(owner=).*(,external-dns)/\1us-east-1:testapp-dev\2/g' <<< "$var1"
```

Now using variable:

```
sed -E "s/(owner=).*(,external-dns)/\1$var2\2/g" <<< "$var1"
```

Note that double quotes are mandatory here for shell to expand variables